# preg_match exclude strings

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

From 10,000 lines of data I have to get all the lines that **don't** contain words that START like "en" or "it" or "de" etc.., that are from 2 to 5 long a-z and A-Z with "-" too (minus sign) and ";"

I tried this but doesn't work

```
 !preg_match("/\b(it|en|de|es|fr|ru)[a-zA-Z-;]{2,5}/", $value)
```

this would be read (to me) don't match all the lines have words that start with it, en, etc. are composed of  2 to 5 chars and in those 5 chars can contain also "-" or ";".

This returns me lines with "it;" which I need to exclude.

EDIT: I need to match every word that starts with those 2 characters (*it* or *en* or *de*) and can be everywhere in the line

Example to match (it doesn't contain words that start with "en", "de", etc.)

```
GET; SITE; 15:03:03; ; Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.1; .NET4.0C);
```

Example not to match (it does contain a word that start with "en")

```
GET; SITE; 13:06:49; ; Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; **en;** MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SIMBAR={E76F6580-EB92-49A3-A089-F6B8B9DEA9AA}; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; eSobiSubscriber 2.0.4.16; Media Center PC 5.0; SLCC1; .NET4.0C); ;
```

Comment: Can you show us some of the data you're matching against?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your regex matches strings that start with one of the country codes and have a total length of *4 - 7*, not 2 - 5. So `en;` does not match because it only contains three symbols. The `{2,5}` applies only to the expression to its immediate left, so your regex reads "A word that starts with it/en/de etc. and continues with between two and five letters/dashes/semicolons." Try `\b(it|en|de|es|fr|ru)[a-zA-Z-;]{0,3}`.

You might also want to be explicit about the semicolon being the last character, and perhaps also be more specific about the structure of the ISO language codes (which I assume that these strings are): `\b(it|en|de|es|fr|ru)(-[a-zA-Z]{2})?;?\b`. Here, we say "A word that starts with it/en/de etc. and might continue with a dash and two letters, and (irrespective of whether it had the dash and two letters) might continue with a semicolon. Nothing else will be allowed before the word should end."

Comment: that worked thanks! I thought that the length would include them too

Comment: @Sandro Antonucci: A reasonable mistake to make. :-) As a general rule, _all_ regex quantifiers (`*`, `?`, `{x}`, and so on) apply only to the expression to their immediate left. I don't think it is possible to specify the total length of the string in any way.

Comment: @Sandro Antonucci: By the way: only use `\b` if you're sure that the words actually will be space-separated. If it's possible that the text could look like e.g. `compatible;en;MSIE 8.0;`, you should (in this specific scenario) use `[\s;(]` (any whitespace character, or a semicolon, or a parenthesis) instead of `\b`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to first split your data into individual lines and then check them one at a time:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $data); // I'm making an assumption here, discussed below.
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
  if (!preg_match('/\b(?=it|en|de|es|fr|ru)[a-z;-]{2,5}/i', $line))
  {
    // line doesn't contain a word beginning with en, de, etc.
  }
}
```

Your use of the `\b` [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) metacharacter should work correctly; `\b` matches at the start of the string if the first character is a word character.

I am using a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (`(?=)`) to check if the first two characters of the word are the language codes you are looking for. This avoids the problem that @Aasmund Eldhuset pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128848/preg-match-exclude-strings/5129016#5129016). In other words, the regular expression engine looks for words that begin with the language codes you want to exclude, but then the result of the match is logically inverted by PHP, so any lines containing those words are ignored.

---

I'm making the assumption that your data is split into lines by a single `\n` (newline) character. It might be split by `\r` or `\n\r` instead. If you don't know which newline characters are being used, you can use [`preg_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) instead of [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), ie:

```
$lines = preg_split('/\n|\n?\r/', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The magic character you're looking for is the caret: `^`:

```
!preg_match("/^(it|en|de|es|fr|ru)[a-zA-Z-;]{2,5}/", $value)
```

Other than that, looks good.

Comment: Not quite. Caret matches the beginning of a **line**, but not the beginning of a **word** (except of course the word that begins the line). `\b` matches a word boundary (which also may not be the beginning of a word, because a word boundary just means the position between a character in `\W` and a character in `\w`).

Comment: that returns me zero lines, but there are lines with any words that start like that

Comment: He says that he wants to ignore **lines** that start with a language code. He doesn't say anything about the rest of the line, which I assume might have other unrelated data.

Comment: From the OP: "all the lines that **don't contain words** that START like "en"..." (emphasis mine). @Sandro, please clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Sandro: When I run into stupid problems like this (i.e., every time I play with Regexes :), I try eliminating parts of it until it works. Try getting rid of the character class part, and leave the lang code part in, and see if that filters properly.

Comment: @Daniel: Oh, whoops. Reading comprehension fail. I guess the right solution might be `[\b^]`?

Comment: @Mike: You can't put metacharacters into a character class like that; the result would be a character class which matches everything other than (`^`) escape character b (`\b`), which if I remember correctly is the backspace character (so `[^\b]` would essentially match all characters). Alternately, `[\b^]` would only match *escape character b* and a literal caret. You can do `(?:^|\b)` instead.

Comment: @Daniel: Please stop exposing my retardedness, it makes me look bad. I of course meant to put the caret second. Or, do what you proposed.

Comment: @Mike: Just trying to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [look-ahead assertion](http://php.net/regexp.reference.assertions):

```
/\b(?!it|en|de|es|fr|ru)[a-zA-Z-;]{2,5}/
```

Here `(?!…)` asserts that there must not be a match of the containing pattern from the current position on without actually matching that pattern.